# Is this flexible drain trap configuration acceptable?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, sink, drainage

I recently redid my entire bathroom (new to all of this), The sink we chose has a draw back we discovered late into the remodel...it has a non-removable drawer that sits almost level with the drain leading into the wall.

I had to come up with a somewhat creative design to allow a p-trap to be implemented. I am a beginner and not sure if this design works. I can run the faucet for minutes at a time and it does not leak. The p-trap appears to hold a large amount of water in it because of the large loop, but perhaps this isn't an issue at all.

Sorry if this seems basic but does this setup seem suitable?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no idea whether this satisfies code or not. But if you ever have to snake the drain you will have no choice but to take the "trap" apart as the snake will have big problems getting through the twists. In addition, I'd be concerned that the flexible ribbed areas could collect dirt, hair, etc. much more than regular pipes.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of where the drawer sits so it is clear what constraint we are working with?

Comment: Or post a different picture from straight on.  From what I think I can see from the odd angle picture you can use standard fittings and none of what they call “uh-o” drain fittings.

Comment: That would be classified as an S-trap. The proper way to fix this is to open that wall and extend the drain pipe in the wall up so that it is level with the exit pipe on a P-trap.

Comment: I don’t think you need that wonky collapsible bendable “uh-oh” plumbing.  I’ll wait and let someone that does this more often tell you how to fix.

Comment: How many inches of clearance do you have between the drawer surface and the bottom of the drain pipe?

Comment: Related question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16380/4979

Comment: @manassehkatz, I'm not sure why anyone would snake a drain from the sink. Disassembling a trap is trivial, and always my first approach.

Comment: @isherwood Generally speaking, you are right, and as far as the "S" that is definitely true (and yes, even a "P"). But even a simple poke down the pipe leading to the trap with something like this https://www.amazon.com/Cobra-Products-00412BL-Drain-Cleaning/dp/B000BO9204 will have problems on the flexible section.

Comment: @unutbu there is roughly 1 inch

Comment: There appears to be at least twice the pipe diameter under it, or 2-1/2".

Comment: There is [some information here](https://structuretech1.com/a-primer-on-s-traps/) on what can go wrong with an S-trap: Siphoning can break the seal, but that usually doesn't happen unless the sink is filled and then drained.

Comment: @Isherwood I will measure again once I get home to provide an exact measurement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That is an absolute mess waiting to happen.

Go to the hardware store, buy a longer tailpipe so you can lower the trap. Aim the pipe off of the trap for the drain you have that is lower than it should be.

You can buy a proper trap that has nut fittings so you can remove it to clean hair, and jewelry out.  You *may* have to cut a small hole in the vanity floor / drawer top to make clearance for the trap. Do not try fudging it with that S trap mess.

Comment: They explain that they can't install the trap low enough to connect to the pipe in the wall due to the cabinet's drawer. The only solution is to open the wall and raise the elbow in the pipe in the wall. so that a proper P-trap can be installed.

Comment: I think the trap could be lowered enough that a slight drop downstream is all that's required. It would be a far cry better than what's there now, and while still not strictly to code it should work just fine.

Comment: [This image](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6BUkSNiXlyM/U-hGNZD4ZoI/AAAAAAAACVk/AhvwK4bFfcY/w1000-h750-no/IMG_5072.JPG) shows basically what I'm suggesting. It's technically an S-trap, but so slight as to be negligable. Of course, you wouldn't create the uphill slope in the trap exit.

Comment: The difference between can't and don't want to may be applied in this post.  If the OP can't install the trap lower because they don't want to cut the vanity, then cutting into the wall would also be a "can't".  The drawer would still open with a hole in the shelf above it. It just means less crap fits in there. That's a horrible design if the drawer is in the back-bottom half of the vanity. What about all the items placed under the sink like in most vanities? How are you going to open that drawer then?

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get a proper p trap in there using smaller pipes with maybe .15 of an inch of clearance from the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I see just a shelf that covers above closed drawer. You need more than 6" of horizontal travel downstream the outlet of the p-trap , you've created an s-trap, not code for a long time
Cut a hole in the wall and remove the part holding the t or wye &raise it , kid's stuff. Do not be intimidated, clear primer & heavy-duty glue, easier than furniture assembly.